# Remove subsection header in Ilmenau beamer theme

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I am doing a presentation with the Ilmenau beamer theme in TexStudio, and I want the dots that specify where I am in the presentation, but I don't want the subsection header (the header located just on top of the title frame, which it's kept blank). I would like to have only the top header and both footers. Does anyone have any idea?

Below is the code I have so far

[image]

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\definecolor{ATLAS}{HTML}{0B80C3}
\usetheme[compress]{Ilmenau}

\usecolortheme{default}
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[framenumber]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=white, bg=ATLAS}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=ATLAS, bg=ATLAS}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white, bg=ATLAS}

\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `\beamer@theme@subsectionfalse` to switch off the subsection bar:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\definecolor{ATLAS}{HTML}{0B80C3}
\usetheme[compress]{Ilmenau}

\makeatletter
\beamer@theme@subsectionfalse
\makeatother

\usecolortheme{default}
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[framenumber]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=white, bg=ATLAS}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=ATLAS, bg=ATLAS}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white, bg=ATLAS}

\begin{document}
\section{title}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
test
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly!

Comment: @Pleba You're welcome!